Obtaining certificates installed on users' Windows machine for digital signatures
We are developing a functionality for our application that lets you digitally sign a .pdf document.
This can be achieved via three methods:

Using a .pfx certificate.
Using one of the certificates installed on the users' machine.
Using a USB token (also plugged on the users' machine).

So far, we've only achieved method number 1. Now, we are having problems in achieving method number 2.
Since our application runs on a Java backend and an Angular frontend, we don't have a way to retrieve the certificates installed on the users' machine.
I've read that something like this could be achieved by using a Java Applet, but since those were deprecated years ago, I was wondering if there's a more modern solution.
Is there any way we can achieve this with the tools we have? Maybe there's an Angular solution for this problem?

This question is similar to: Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If the question for your scenario (2) is how to obtain a file from the local machine, the (java) backend is irrelevant - it has no access to the user's machine.
If the angular application is running in a browser, then the answer is NO - browser-hosted application have no access to the local file system, unless you use the browser's file upload facility and ask the user to locate the file and upload it (to the backend).
If the angular application is running locally on the machine (because you've packaged it on Node and installed that on the machine), then the answer is yes since you will have (some access) to the local file system.  Then the question is: does the user who is running the node application have permission to see where this certificate is stored.  (How does your application know where to look?)

Hi. The Angular application is running on a browser, so I guess that's out of the question. Is the Java Applet the only solution to this problem, then? I thought there would be a more modern solution, given that Java applets are obsolete now.
